# Fetching Parent and All Children of Parent (including 'this' row)

Tags: sql, self-join

I have a self-join scenario where linkedAssignment_id is the parent and itself is an assignment (defined in Assignment table).

I have:

```
assignment_id: 1 with no parent.
assignment_id: 2 with 1 as parent.
assignment_id: 3 with 1 as parent.
```

Given either 1 or 2 or 3,I want to return (1, 2, 3). In other words, if the primary key of the parent is given I need to get id's of all the children + parent. Or if the id or any child is given, i want to return it's parent and all the siblings (including this sibling).

I came up with the following, it looks clunky and inefficient, can somebody please provide some pointers?

```
select assignment_id  
from assignment a 
where linkedassignment_id = 3
or assignment_id = 3
union 
(
select assignment_id  
from assignment a 
where linkedassignment_id in ( 
    select linkedassignment_id from assignment b  where assignment_id = 3
    ) 
    union 
    select linkedassignment_id from assignment b  where assignment_id = 3
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a table where one record refers another, that record refers yet another, etc (like pointers in a tree), there's no easy way to select a subtree using purely relational means.

If you were using Oracle, you could turn to its `connect by` operator created specifically for cases like this.

Other techniques exist to help this. Most used are these:

- Store the entire path to the root inside every node, as a text string. Say, your node has `path = 'foo.bar.baz'`; it means that this node is `baz`, its parent is `bar`, and the root is `foo`. To efficiently select a subtree starting at `bar`, use `select ... where path like 'foo.bar.%'`. To select a particular node, use a full path. The `path` column should be indexed, of course. This approach works best with trees few levels deep.
- Store the tree using [nested sets](http://threebit.net/tutorials/nestedset/tutorial1.html). It's a bit more hairy but may be easier to manipulate (e.g. move subtrees around).